# Postgres Driver not pointing to correct jar version on Spring

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am in the development team of an application in a monolithic structure.

Technical details;
Maven 3.8.1 version
Java 8
Previous Postgres version: 42.2.16.jre7

My problem is that;
I want to upgrade Postgres version from 42.2.16.jre7 to 42.5.1.
I do this upgrade in the pom file, I can pull the package with maven and I see the jar comes in the .m2 folder.
In the application.prop file, I use the following definition:
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
I see Driver still looking at the old version when hovering over it.

Methods I have tried;

- Deleting the old version files from the m2 and ensuring that only the version I want remains. I hover over Driver in App.prop and click on the warning "Add library 'Driver xxx..' to classpath". But when I start the application, it downloads the old version and continues to look at it.
- I removed the old jars from Intellij -> File -> Project -> Project Structure -> Libraries. I re-added the jar I wanted.

When I do these, when I hover over Driver in app.prop, I see that it points to the version I want. But when I start the application, it downloads the old jars again.

Note: There are pom files under other modules in the application, I checked that it does not pull a different version of postgres in those poms.

In summary, how can I make the application look at the version I want?

4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.hx.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-spring-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../core-spring-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>core-service</artifactId>

<properties>
    <hazelcast.version>3.8.3</hazelcast.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hx.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-context</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hx.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>hx-address-clean</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.5.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
                <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bitsofinfo</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-docker-swarm-discovery-spi</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-RC3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.craftsman</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer-jdk8-support</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>newrelic-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.14</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hx.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>hx-dist-cache</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.15</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/ZsdHxCargoStatuEnt.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/ZsdHxCargoStatuEnt.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml` to the question to see what the issue is. As the issue is probably in your pom.xml and how you declare/use the dependency.

Comment: run mvn dependency tree in order to see where it comes from. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

I examined it in detail with Dependency Analyzer, but I could not find where this dependency was added. As a solution, I added the following dependency to the poms of all the modules I have.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And now when I hover over the "spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver" setting in application.properties I see it points to version 42.5.1 and not the old version.

Comment: Of course in this way it works but it's not the correct approach. Use `mvn dependency:tree` as suggested above.

Comment: Might solve your problem right now, but you don't have a clear view of the consequences, because this dependency might pull in transitive dependencies which might conflict and break other parts of the system. Please check with previous suggestion.